# Implementing CICD Pipeline for a Angular Project with CircleCI and AWS S3

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, continuous-integration, circleci

I want to implement continuous delivery pipeline for my angular project using Github, CircleCI and hosting it to AWS S3, I am quite confused with setting up CircleCI config file for angular build and S3 deployment, any help is most appretiated.

Comment: Please specify what you tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post - https://medium.freecodecamp.org/our-journey-for-using-circleci-2-0-to-build-and-deploy-an-angular-app-to-aws-s3-8e7ea3f51503

I have personally done this with Jenkins and it was pretty straight-forward and took a few hours to get it up and running.